# vaccine success CDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A group of people is vaccinated twice (with two different vaccines). The probability of the **first vaccine not working** is **0.08**, and the probability that **the second vaccine doesn't work for the person for whom the first didn't work is 0.2**. The probability of the **second vaccine not working for the person for whom the first vaccine worked** is **0.05**. If we consider two people, find the CDF for the following random variables:

**X** - number of people for whom the first vaccine doesn't work

**Y** - number of people for whom the second vaccine doesn't work

This is seriously confusing, I don't even know where to start, or how to find these CDFs. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

X is easy, as the first one working or not does not depend on the second one at all. Y is a little harder: You can divide it up into two parts:

1. The first one works, but the second one doesn't.
2. Both don't work.

Now you can compute the probabilities of these two, add them up and you have Y.

Comment: Thanks, it's much more clear now. Can you just explain a bit more how exactly I could calculate the CDF of either X or Y.

Comment: Really? If you are asking that, nothing is clear at all... X is given in your question, there is nothing to calculate. Y is easy to calculate if you understood what to do, so I think you might lacking some really basic knowledge that goes beyond this question...

Comment: but I was just wondering which distribution should I use... Is it binomial, or normal or what..

Answer (score 1):

For computing the CDFs, all you need to know are the probabilities $P(X=m)
$ and $P(Y=n)$ for nonnegative integers $m$ and $n$. I assume that the vaccination of one person is an event independent of the vaccination of another, and also hope you have been able to compute $P(X=m)$ straightforwardly.

For the second part, you may do the following: let's say we want to compute $P(Y=n)$. Then, among these $n$ people, for a certain number $m$ of them, where $0\leq m\leq n$, the first vaccine might not have worked. So, we have to first compute $P(Y=n|X=m)$, and thereafter, it is obvious by the law of total probability that

\begin{equation}
P(Y=n)=\sum\limits_{m=0}^{n} P(Y=n|X=m)\cdot P(X=m).
\end{equation}

Now, $P(Y=n|X=m)=\binom{n}{m}(0.2)^{m}(0.05)^{n-m}$ since there are $m$ people for which the first vaccine has not worked and the probability of the second vaccine not working for these people is $0.2$; similarly, there are $n-m$ people for whom the first vaccine has worked, and for these people, the second vaccine will not work with probability $0.05$. Finally, there are $\binom{n}{m}$ ways of choosing $m$ people out of $n$.

Comment: the probability of the second vaccine not working if the first one works is 0.05, I made a mistake when writing the question, but I edited it now. Also, would it be wrong if I calculated the probability of the second vaccine not working like this : (see my next comment)

Comment: let's say **A** is the event of the first vaccine not working and **B** is the event of the second vaccine not working.. so I would calculate $P(B)$ like this: $P(B)=P(B|A)\dot P(A) + P(B|A^c) \dot P(A^c)$.. so than I would use this $P(B)$ as the probability in calculating $P(Y=n)$, where $n$ goes from 0 to 2

Comment: @ivana14 In some sense, this is what I have done. I have conditioned on the event that for $m$ out of $n$ persons, the first vaccine has not worked. This is equivalent to conditioning on the event that for $n-m$ persons, the first vaccine has worked. Both $A$ and $A^{c}$ appear intrinsically in my calculations.