# CDFs of X and Y

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A group of people is vaccinated twice (with two different vaccines). The probability of the first vaccine not working is 0.08, and the probability that the second vaccine doesn't work for the person for whom the first didn't work is 0.2. The probability of the second vaccine not working for the person for whom the first vaccine worked is 0.05. If we consider **two** people, find the CDF for the following random variables:

X - number of people for whom the first vaccine doesn't work

Y - number of people for whom the second vaccine doesn't work

Now, I have calculated the probabilities for $X=0$, $X=1$ and $X=2$.
I was wondering if it would be correct do calculate the probability for the second vaccine not working like this:

let's say $A$ is the event of the first vaccine not working and $B$ is the event of the second vaccine not working.. so I would calculate $P(B)$ like this: $P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^c)P(A^c)$.. so than I would use this $P(B)$ as the probability for calculating the probabilities of $Y=0$, $Y=1$ and $Y=2$

Comment: Sounds correct.

Comment: Repeat of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277657/vaccine-success-cdf ?